# How to prevent texture tiling in texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting, brushes

I think it should work if I go to Texture properties and in the dropdown Extension try to switch from extend to clip but when I do that my brushes stop working. I can't paint, nothing happens when I click on the object to paint.

Also it seems the brushes randomly switch to the basic paintbrush when I switch between the tool settings tab and the texture properties tabs. How do you actually choose a brush because choosing a brush in the active tool/Brushes doesn't seem to affect this sometimes? Usually just switching back and forth with blend modes and tabs forces it to use the brush I wanted...?

Comment: Can you show some screen shots of what you are experiencing? I can't tell from the description if you are affecting a change to the Brush Texture or the Material Image Texture. What version of Blender are you using for painting, and what layout are you using while painting? Have you enabled the Dynamic Brush Menu addon inside preferences that allows control from a single spacebar press while painting?